# Magento 2.3 reindex design_config_grid stucks on processing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, reindex, indexer

**design_config_grid** and **customer_grid** stuck on processing when I use `bin/magento indexer:reindex`. Even after `bin/magento indexer:reset` and changing status to *Invalid*, when I reindex again, they stuck on processing and I get this message: `State for the same view already exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into the same problem this week. Was able to fix it using the database. Don't know if all steps are necessary:

1. Disable all cron's
2. run bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. Go to tabel mview_state in your db. Check for duplicate view_id entries (mine where: design_config_dummy & customer_dummy) and remove them.
4. Run bin/magento setup:upgrade (pretty sure you can run bin/magento indexer:reindex as well)
5. Enable all cron's

Answer (score 0):

Can you please used this if you stuck

```
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reset
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid customer_grid
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule
    php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product
```

Thank you

Comment: Same error message for design_config_grid and customer_grid .

Comment: First reset all

Comment: I did. Same error.